# Simulate a Gaussian Copula with t margins

Tags: probability, simulation, copula, marginal-distribution

The task is the following:

Given is $Z_1,...Z_{50}$ different hypothetical assets.

Each $Z_k \sim t_3$ with standard deviation $\sigma=0.01$ and $\tau(Z_i,Z_k)=0.4$ for $j\neq k$.

I want to simulate from the distribution $(Z_1,...,Z_{50})$ assuming that it has a Gaussian Copula with $t_3$ margins.

For what I understand, from the kendals tau $\tau$ I can estimate the correlation parameter $\rho=sin(\pi\tau/2)=0.5878$. From this I can determina the covariance matrix when I do want to do the simulation. Here is the code:

```
require(mvtnorm)
N <- 1000
tau <- 0.4
correlation <- sin(pi*tau/2)
std <- 0.01

S <- matrix((std^2)*correlation,50,50
for (i in 1:50) {

        S[i,i] <- std^2

}

gauss <- rmvt(N, sigma = S, df = 3)
U_norm <- pnorm(gauss)
Z_gauss <- qt(U_norm,df=3)
plot(Z_gauss[,1],Z_gauss[,2])
```

However, this method is not correct. I cannot see any plot that resembles a gaussian copula. Any thoughts, corrections?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "cannot see any plot that resembles a gaussian copula"?  I am puzzled by this because (1) there are no plotting commands or images in your post and (2) this copula exists in 50 dimensions.  I am also curious why in your penultimate line `pnorm(gauss)` you do not refer to `S`.  Incidentally, typos and missing commands (such as one that defines `rmvt`) in your code will make it impossible to execute.

Comment: rmvt is for generating from multidimensional t distribution. I added the library in the top. Also, added plotting code.

Comment: Great, thank you.  May I direct your attention to the one part of my comment you have not yet addressed?  It may hold the key to the problem: why are you applying `pnorm`, which is the distribution function of a *standard* Normal variate, when `gauss` contains variables whose marginal distributions are given by the *nonstandard* covariance matrix `S`?

Comment: Not sure... how should it in that case be done? I use pnorm for since I want to create a Gaussian Copula, however, i just checked that the histogram of U_norm is NOT uniformly distributed. Any help what to do?

Answer (score 3):

There's an R package called "copula" that will let you do exactly this.

The process goes:

1. Specify a copula
2. Specify the population distribution, including whatever marginals you want. [From the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf): "A user-defined distribution, for example, fancy, can be used as margin provided that `dfancy`, `pfancy`, and `qfancy` are available."
3. Generate samples from that multivariate distribution.

For you, you would specify a Gaussian copula in step 1 and then say that you want t-distributed marginals in step 2.

```
# Step 1
#
my_copula <- normalCopula(0.8)

# Step 2
#
my_population <- mvdc(my_copula, c("t","t"),list(t=3,t=3))

# Step 3
#
my_sample <- rMvdc(1000,my_population)
```

**Caveat**: I don't have access to this package right now, so I can't swear that this will compile, though it gives the gist of what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the approach you're attempting to implement would proceed as follows:

1. Generate sample from a multivariate normal with the desired correlation matrix
2. transform each margin from normal to uniform (in R, `pnorm` is suitable), to obtain a sample from the required copula
3. transform each margin from uniform to the desired $t$ distribution (in R, `qt` will do that)

Comment: +1. Watch out, though: `qt` will produce infinite values especially with small degrees of freedom. The extreme t tails will make it practically impossible to gauge whether the resulting multivariate distribution follows a Gaussian copula. One should study the distribution of the *uniform* versions (in 2) rather than the distribution of the t variates (in 3).

Comment: @whuber the question asks for t-margins, so I don't see how to avoid attempting some transform from normal to $t_3$; of course one might try to implement a more direct approach there. However, I just generated 10 million values from a uniform and transformed via `qt` without getting a single non-finite value returned. How often are you seeing it?

Comment: It looks like making use of `lower.tail=FALSE` in `qt` with a check for being in the upper half will make it an event that would happen less than once in a googol times for each tail. When I get back I'll look at whether to lay that out in detail.

Comment: With df=3, I was seeing it relatively frequently.  I didn't check, but it was on the order of a percent or so.  I was using a minor variation of the OP's code, corrected to use the proper SD and to generate 6-D vectors rather than 50-D vectors (which are much harder to examine in detail!)

Comment: @whuber But nothing so complex is required to check the effect of `qt`  -- each marginal will be uniform and we're only transforming the margins, so we only have to check the frequency with which `qt(runif(...),3)` has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will try to answer this. I am using Python code for ease.

**THEORY**

First, lets explicitly define your correlation matrix 
$$R^{50\times50} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
.01&.4 &\cdots&.4 \\
.4 & \ddots&  &.4 \\
\vdots&&\ddots &\vdots\\
.4 &\cdots &\cdots &.01
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then, since we are using a Gaussian copula to model the joint distrubtion of $z_1,...,z_{50}$, we have: $C_{\textit{Gauss}}(u_1,...,u_{50}) = Pr[U_1 \leq u_1, ..., U_{50}\leq u_{50}] = \Phi_R(x_1, ..., x_{50})$, where $\Phi_R$ is the multivariate normal CDF with correlation matrix $R$ and mean $\mathbf{0}$, $x_i$ is a Gaussian standard normal random variable, and $\Phi(x_i) = u_i$ is the standard normal CDF. Often this copula is written as

$$C_{\textit{Gauss}} (u_1,...,u_{50}) = \Phi_R(\Phi^{-1}(u_1),...,\Phi^{-1}(u_{50})),$$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse standard normal CDF, thus $\Phi^{-1}(u_i)$ gives us a standard normal random variable $x_i$!

Lastly, we note that $u_i = F(Z_i)$, where $Z_i \sim t_3$ is your t-distributed random variable and $F$ is the CDF of your t-distrubted random variable. Thus, with a Gaussian copula, we first calculate the CDF of your random variable ($Z_i$ in this case), which gives $u_i$. We then take the inverse standard normal CDF of $u_i$, which gives us a standard normal random variable $\Phi^{-1}(u_i) = x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. We do this for each $Z_i$. Then after getting all the standard normal variables $x_1,...x_{50}$, we look at the CDF of their joint distribution. Because each $x_i$ is a standard normal random variables, the joint distribution of all $x_i$'s is a multivariate normal distribution! Thus, the CDF of this joint distribution is $\Phi_R$, the reason we can use a correlation matrix as our covariance matrix is because each $x_i$ has mean 0, and variance 1, so the covariance matrix is already normalized to 1!

**PROCEDURE**

With all of this in mind. We can now write the procedure for sampling from this copula.

1. Sample $u_1, ..., u_{50}$ from your Gaussian copula. $$u_1, ..., u_{50} \sim C_{\text{Gauss}}(u_1,...,u_{50}).$$ Here are the steps to do this as your copula is Gaussian

   a. Since $C_{\text{Gauss}}(u_1,...,u_{50}) = \Phi_R(x_1, ..., x_{50})$, as described above, first sample $x_1,...,x_{50}$ from a joint normal multivariate distribution with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and correlation $R$
   $$ x_1,...,x_{50} \sim \mathrm{Multi}(0,R).$$ There are many Python and R packages that can do this quickly and easily.

   b. Once you have $x_1,...,x_{50}$, take the standard normal CDF of each $x_i$
    $$ \Phi(x_1),...,\Phi(x_{50}) = u_1,...,u_{50}.$$ This will give you your uniform marginals $u_1,...,u_{50}$
2. Now that you have $u_1,...,u_{50}$, note for each of your t-distributed $Z_i$, that $F(Z_i) = u_i$, where $F$ is the CDF of the t-distribution. Thus to get $Z_1, ...,Z_{50}$ simply take the inverse of the CDF for each $u_i$. 
            $$F^{-1}(u_1), ... , F^{-1}(u_{50}) = Z_1, ..., Z_{50}$$

**Implementation**
Here is the implementation of the above steps in Python

```
'''Simulate from a Gaussian Copula with t-margins
variance = .01
variance amongst covariates (correlation)  = .4
'''
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss

n = 1 # The number of samples
p = 50 # The number of covariates
# the mean of the multivariate Gaussian CDF is zero
mu = np.zeros(p)
The correlation matrix R with R_ii = .01, R_ij = .4
correlation_matrix_r = np.zeros((p,p))
for i in range(n):
     for j in range(n):
           if (i != j):
                 correlation_matrix_r[i,j] = .4
           else:
                 correlation_matrix_r[i,j] = .01

# Step 1: sample u_1, ..., u_50 from copula

# a. Get standard normal random variables x_1,...,x_50 ~ N(0,1)
x_is = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, correlation_matrix_r, size = (n,p))

# b. Get the uniform marginals u_1,..,u_50 from the standard normal random variables
# Do this by taking the standard normal CDF for each x_i
# ss.norm(x_is) will take the the standard normal CDF of each element in x_is
uniform_marginals_u = ss.norm(x_is)

# Step 2: The invese t-distrubtion CDF of each uniform marginal to get your samples
# F^{-1}(u_1),...,F^{-1}(u_50) = Z_1, ...,Z_50

# get t-distrubtion object from scipy, with specified parameters
t_3 = ss.t(df = 3)
t_dist_samples_z = t_3.ppf(uniform_marginals_u) #ppf is the inverse cdf
```

This code will give you $n$ samples of $Z_1,..Z_{50}$. 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\{(Z_1,...Z_{50})_1 \\ \vdots \\ (Z_1,...Z_{50})_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Hope this helped!